# FIPS 201(-2): Central requirements for PIV?

Tags: smartcard, certification, fips

I was recentely asked in the comments on some details on tamper-proofing of a smartcard in question. The term "FIPS-201" was used to specify what kind of details was needed.

I understand that FIPS 140-2 defines four levels of hardware (/software) security for smartcards / software / HSMs for these devices to protect, use and manage keys.

When "asked" for FIPS-201, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_201) says that this is a set of requirements for personal identity validation (PIV). So a piece of soft-/ hardware can either be FIPS-201 compliant or not.

But none of the pages stated what those requirements actually are, hence my question:

**What are the central requirements for PIV as per FIPS-201?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.201-2.pdf) is a link to the FIPS 201 document on NIST's website.

This is pulled from the linked document and might directly answer your question:

`The PIV Card shall contain security features that aid in reducing counterfeiting, are resistant to tampering, and provide visual evidence of tampering attempts. At a minimum, a PIV Card shall incorporate one such security feature. 
Examples of these security features include the following:
• optical varying structures;
• optical varying inks;
• laser etching and engraving;
• holograms;
• holographic images; and
• watermarks.`